# In GitHub, Is it possible to know the languages composition a year back?

Tags: github

In github, we can easily find the % of languages on the repo such as below
[image]

However, my understanding, this is the latest Master %. If I want to look back a year ago etc, is that possible? Any git command that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub uses **Linguist** ([source](https://github.com/github/linguist)) to calculate the usage of languages in a repository and show it. So essentially there is no git command to calculate that.

However, you can install **Linguist** ([steps](https://github.com/github/linguist#installation)) on your local machine, go to the directory of your repo/project on your local machine, use **git** to **checkout to an older commit** (`git checkout <old_commit_hash>`), and use **Linguist** to calculate the usage of languages by running the command

```
github-linguist --breakdown
```

which should give you the usage of languages as below for example

```
68.57%  Ruby
22.90%  C
6.93%   Go
1.21%   Lex
0.39%   Shell

Ruby:
Gemfile
Rakefile
bin/git-linguist
bin/github-linguist
ext/linguist/extconf.rb
github-linguist.gemspec
lib/linguist.rb
…
```

The command-line usage instructions are provided [here](https://github.com/github/linguist#command-line-usage) in the Linguist readme.